# How to power off discrete graphics card

Tags: kernel, lubuntu, power-management, gpu

I installed Lubuntu 16.04 to my HP Pavilion dv6 laptop which has AMD 6770M discrete graphics card. In order to save battery I want to power off AMD card since onboard Intel HD3000 is enough for me. I have tried several options only one of them worked for me. 
I edited `/etc/rc.local` file and added the following line

```
echo OFF > /sys/kernel/debug/vgaswitcheroo/switch
```

It completely switched off the AMD GPU but when I shut down or lock the computer it freezes up.

Does anybody have an opinion about that? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you take a look in BIOS if there is some option to disable discrete card?

Comment: read logs of what's going on before/during/after the hang. The /var/log folder has some useful information. Get familiar with what each file is for, try to find the cause.

Comment: I wrestled with this problem for over a month before finally reinstalling 14.04. Now it works as it should and the AMD card stays powered off. Had all kinds of scripts to fix things but to no avail. When you force the card off, check dmesg after a while and you'll see all the errors it causes.

Comment: NonStandardModel - No, unfortunately there is no option in BIOS to disable the GPU. 
piotrektt - Thanks. I will check the log files.
Dorian - Hopefully somebody will find a solution. I found some other people asking similar questions.